# can't rake, missing gem but it's available

Tags: server, rails, gem

I'm trying to `rake` but I keep getting this

[image]

As you can see, `i18n (0.6.4)` is installed and alive, so what's going on? what am I missing?

I have tried to uninstall and install again, all went well but got the same error after :/

```
sudo gem uninstall i18n
sudo bundle install
```

even tried install it using `sudo gem install i18n`, it installed, but got the same error...

btw, the application is Redmine, the one I'm trying to rake myself into...

using Ubuntu Server 12.10 x64 on Amazon EC2 (micro instance)

Comment: Perhaps trying `bundle update`? I don't add this as an answer because I'm not sure, but you could try it :P

Comment: @AddisonMontgomery I did that, but get the same problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/utV5Y.png

Comment: Could you paste the output of `cat Gemfile` and `bundle show i18n`?

Comment: `cat GemFile` in [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/j2LMmu9d), and `bundle show i18n` gives `Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources`... but as I mentioned in my question, I did uninstall and installed (through `bundle` and through `gem`)  :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing the Gemfile using this command:

```
$ nano Gemfile
```

Then, replace the line:

```
gem "i18n", "~> 0.6.0"
```

With this one:

```
gem "i18n", "0.6.4"
```

To save it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Now, try running again:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle update
$ rake generate_secret_token
```

I'm not sure if it will work, but I hope so!

Comment: works lovely! Muchas gracias por ayuda :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with `Could not find metaclass-0.0.1 in any of the sources` and I have edited `Gemfile` and even added `gem "metaclass", "0.0.1"` without luck :/ dang... I'm hating my adventure in Ubuntu :(